# htaccess: использование %1 и %2 в RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

В рамках приведения к ЧПУ на сайте были изменены адреса страниц.
Реализация была через одну точку входа, хотя к вопросу это, наверное, не относится:

```
    RewriteRule ^akb/(.*)$ /url-processor.php
```

Для исключения дублей страниц теперь нужно сделать переадресацию, например:
catalog.php?boxtype=b24&page=3 => akb/boxtype/b24/page-3

Пробовал так:

```
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} boxtype=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=([0-9]+)
    RewriteRule catalog.php /akb/boxtype/%1/page-%2? [R=301,L]
```

Ожидал, что вместо %1 подставится "b24", вместо %2 - "3".
Фактически переадресация идет на /akb/boxtype/3/page-, т. е. %1 = "3", %2 = "".
Почему не %1 = "b24", %2 = "3", и как использовать сразу две переменных?

Дополнение.
Ответ на вопрос "почему" получен.
Пришел в голову вариант решения:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} boxtype=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)
RewriteRule catalog.php catalog.php/%1 [QSA]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule catalog.php/(.*) /akb/boxtype/$1/page-%1? [R=301,L]
```

Вроде, переадресовывает, куда нужно.
Но с htaccess опыта работы вообще нет. Может быть, есть более изящное решение? Или подводные камни в предложенном варианте...

Comment: и с чего вы это ожидали, если в документации черным по белому написано, что `%N` содержит значения N-ной группы из последнего `RewriteCond`, а не из всех подряд ?

Comment: В паре десятков прочитанных материалов по этой теме никто не написал, что это будет из последнего RewriteCond. Вы первый подсказали, спасибо!

Comment: материалы стоит  читать когда первоначальная документация не понятна ) https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html